# How to run a R script in a remote way?

Tags: r, remote-access

I need to execute an R script. It takes approximately 2 days to run on my machine which is very costly. Is there some service that I could use to run it remotely on a machine supplied by third parties? It's a newbie question and any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest running your code on Microsoft Azure or RStudio Server. Here is the documentation for the AzureML package which provides an interface from R to the Azure Cloud. I hope this helps.

[AzureML Documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/AzureML/versions/0.2.15)

Answer (score 0):

Many cloud services offer virtual machines which would be perfect for this.  Many offer free, albeit small, configurations so it need not cost anything.